# Syntax coloring doesn't show on Cross Validated (stats) site

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

Syntax highlighting doesn't appear to work on [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com).

For instance, see the question [PyMC for Categorical Latent Model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/156020/pymc-for-categorical-latent-model) which is set to use the Python language syntax via:

```
<!-- language: python -->
```

Other sites such as stackoverflow.com work fine, however.

**Update: referenced page (PyMC for Categorical Latent Model) has since been edited to use the solution provided in the accepted answer. However, screenshot below accurately reflects the state when "language: python" is used instead of "language: lang-python"**

[image]

A related problem [was reported on CS50](https://cs50.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40/why-is-there-no-syntax-highlighting), but that was to do with syntax highlighting simply not being available on the site in general.

Comment: Voting to reopen, this pertains to any coding site.

Comment: But @nicael OP says it works fine on SO...?

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ My mistake, see the edit please.

Comment: In the example provided, syntax is highlighted for me. Also, this still only pertains to a specific site unless you show this also fails on another site. And stating "this is fine on Stack Overflow" goes *against* it not being specific to one site :)

Comment: Voting to reopen because this affects 2 sites

Comment: @Tim how only two sites? *Any* coding sites.

Comment: @nicael well it works on code golf...

Comment: @Tim What works, exactly? Have you read my answer?.. Or [this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260157/syntax-coloring-doesnt-show-on-cross-validated-stats-site?noredirect=1#comment848319_260158)?

Comment: Which site other than "Cross Validated" does this not work on? It keeps going into the review queue, and I and others keep clicking "Leave closed" because there seems to be no evidence this is a problem on more than the one site (Cross Validated) as per the question content and the title.

Comment: Well, my question to begin with was a misunderstanding, since syntax highlighting does work perfectly fine so long as you know how to use it. Nonetheless, as the result of this question I have discovered how exactly syntax highlighting works and what exceptions apply. And, as it turns out, the syntax highlighting mechanism is the same on every SE site where it is employed, so the information happens to apply to all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the site doesn't have the syntax highlighting bind to special tag, the following syntax should be used:

```
<!-- language: lang-python -->
```

In case of Stack Overflow, [python](/questions/tagged/python) has python syntax highlighting applied, so when you write: `language: python`, it does mean: use the syntax highlighting which is used by [python](/questions/tagged/python) tag. As for Stats, there's no python highlighting bind to the [python](/questions/tagged/python), therefore it's invalid to use `language: python`, but you should use the syntax I've mentioned: `language: lang-python`, which does mean: use the highlighting applied to the python *language*.

More info: https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting

[I've suggested the edit to fix the highlighting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/69146).

Comment: Ok, but then why does "python" alone work just fine on stackoverflow? For example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18987697/how-to-model-a-mixture-of-3-normals-in-pymc

Comment: @MD004 because I guess that [pymc] tag has the according default syntax highlighting set on SO, but not on stats.

Comment: Removing <!-- language: python --> turns the coloring off, so it doesn't appear to default to python for those posts. Nonetheless, you did answer my original question.

Comment: @md0 hm, this is strange. Probably the option without "lang-" is only for SO, because, as you see, I've never considered it to be a valid one.

Comment: @MD004 the (lang-)-less syntax is only when the tags has an assigned highlight. If the lang-less string doesn't match a tag which has syntax highlighting enabled, then the shortcut doesn't work.

Comment: Ohh I see what you mean now. The [help page](http://stats.stackexchange.com/editing-help) says _You can use either one of the supported prettify language codes, like lang-cpp, or you can specify a tag, and the syntax highlighting language associated with this tag will be used_, which I just realized means that "language: python" actually means **use the language associated with the tag [python] if that tag exists on the site and is associated with a language**. So, it's nothing to do with the [pymc] tag, nor does it matter that the post itself is not tagged with [python]. Makes sense now!

Comment: @MD004 nice investigation, I've edited my question a bit to be more useful for future visitors :)